# Bitcoin-cli transaction viewing

Tags: bitcoin-cli

I am attempting to create my own Bitcoin API for a website I have been building over the recent years and I need some sort of transaction system to handle payments with Bitcoin. I currently own a plethora of Bitcoin addresses already and so if possible, I could recycle those without needing to have the computing power to constantly make a new address.

My logic behind the code it is that I will have a request sent to the server stating that a transaction has been started with a given address. Every so often, I need to check this address for a transaction that is newer than the timestamp of the log which says '[timestamp] a new transaction has started with x address'. I will then track the balance of this transaction and if it becomes the amount I wish it to be then I will respond to the server stating that the transaction has been complete.

Although this may sound complicated, it sort-of already works using a third part API but instead, I would instead like to use the Bitcoin-Cli to check transactions of a given address rather than relying on some shoddy API that stops my code from working half the time.

If anyone has the know-how please let me know as that would be fantastic! If anyone knows a better alternative to this system then please let me know too.

Comment: There are few libraries available for btcpayserver: https://docs.btcpayserver.org/CustomIntegration/ and btcpayserver uses bitcoin core

Comment: @Prayank Surely can't I just use Bitcoin core raw?

Comment: You can write everything from scratch and use bitcoin core but I suggested an easier approach

Comment: @Prayank Yeah I suppose so and appreciated, need at least a barebones project to get me off the ground really. Would you happen to know where I could how to use bitocin core in conjunction with PHP?

Comment: You might find few helpful links in google or here with keywords: _json rpc php bitcoin_